# Update dictionary/list with similar key but different value & show as report in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, updates

I need an update function to loop around and check which key being used to encrypt files.

```
import os

i = {}
dictionary = {}

def encr_key():
    try:
        # Select the main file to encrypt
        print("Step 1: Please select your Main File (Plain Text) that you want to encrypt : ")
        
        # Select location to save the encrypted file
        print("Step 2: Please select a directory to save the encrypted file : ")
       
            # Encryption process
            
            # Update key & value in the dictionary
            dictionary .update({key_file.name: encrypt_file})
```

Comment: better always use list for values - even if you have only one value - because then it is easier to add next value - `{key2: [encryptfile3]}` and `{key3: [encryptfile4]}`

Comment: better create minimal working code with your problem - without `tkiner`,etc. but with example data directly in code.

Comment: you could evnt use `collections.defaultdict(list)` to make it simpler.

Comment: I don't uderstand why you use `while True` - it is useless. And why you use `k = encrypt_key_value_dict.keys()` and `v = encrypt_key_value_dict.values()` if you need rather `k = key_file.name` and `v = encrypt_file`

Comment: Sorry I was trying something to test with ```while``` loop to check whether any existing data or not. I am checking now. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting this error while append - any thoughts? ```encrypt_key_value_dict[k].append(v) - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' ```

Comment: because you have to create list to keep more than one item - see code in my answers - I first check if exists `[k]` and if it doesn't exist then I first create list and add new value. If you assign single string then you can't append next value because you don't have list - you have to remove also `encrypt_key_value_dict.update(...)`

Answer (score 0):

This part is useless

**EDIT:** I added `encrypt_key_value_dict.update(...)` to this example

```
        encrypt_key_value_dict.update(...)

        while True:
            k = encrypt_key_value_dict.keys()
            v = encrypt_key_value_dict.values()
            if i in encrypt_key_value_dict:
                encrypt_key_value_dict[k].append(v)
            else:
                encrypt_key_value_dict[k] = [v]

            print(encrypt_key_value_dict)
```

You don't need `while True` loop to add single element. And you use wrong values in `k`, `v`,

You need

```
k = key_file.name
v = encrypt_file
```

---

```
encrypt_key_value_dict = dict()

k = 'key1'         # key_file.name
v = 'encryptfile1' # encrypt_file

# first method
if k in encrypt_key_value_dict:
    encrypt_key_value_dict[k].append(v)
else:
    encrypt_key_value_dict[k] = [v]

k = 'key1'         # key_file.name
v = 'encryptfile2' # encrypt_file

# second method
if k not in encrypt_key_value_dict:
    encrypt_key_value_dict[k] = []
encrypt_key_value_dict[k].append(v)

print(encrypt_key_value_dict)
```

---

If you use `collections.defaultdict(list)` then it can be even simpler

```
import collections

encrypt_key_value_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

k = 'key1'         # key_file.name
v = 'encryptfile1' # encrypt_file

encrypt_key_value_dict[k].append(v)

k = 'key1'         # key_file.name
v = 'encryptfile2' # encrypt_file

encrypt_key_value_dict[k].append(v)

print(dict(encrypt_key_value_dict))
```